# Correct way to use Django's ORM and Django Rest Framework to serialize a queryset of nested relationships?

Tags: python, json, django, django-rest-framework, django-orm

What is the correct way to build a queryset that I can pass into a Django Rest Framework Serializer so as to get a data/json result of related nested objects.

For example, I have two models:

```
class Topping(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Pizza(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    toppings = models.ManyToManyField(Topping)
```

And my serializers:

```
class ToppingSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    name = serializers.CharField(required=True, max_length=50)

class PizzaSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    name = serializers.CharField(required=True, max_length=50)
    toppings = ToppingSerializer(many=True, required=False)
```

How do I then create and pass in a query set to get the outcome of something like this:

```
[
  {
    "name": "Hawaiian",
    "toppings": [
      {"name": "Pinapple"},
      {"name": "Canadian Bacon"},
      {"name": "Cheese"}
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "Pepperoni Pizza",
    "toppings": [
      {"name": "Pepperoni"},
      {"name": "Cheese"}
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "Jamaican",
    "toppings": [
      {"name": "Chicken"},
      {"name": "Jerk"},
      {"name": "Cheese"}
    ]
  }
]
```

---

#### Please Note:

The Django Rest Framework has a good [example in their documentation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#nested-relationships) using ModelSerializer, but I will need this functionality without using ModelSerializer as my serialization needs will become quite customized beyond the DB model representations.

---

#### Additional Information:

The Django Rest Framework documentation for "[Dealing with nested objects](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#dealing-with-nested-objects)" is helpful, but I'm still not sure how to pass the correct queryset to such a "nested object serializer".

How can I create a "nested" queryset?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all you need to use [`ModelSerializer`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#modelserializer) instead of `Serializer`, and provide [`fields`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#specifying-which-fields-to-include) meta attribute. If you are using default field configuration you don't need to provide serializer fields explicitly.

```
class ToppingSerializer(serializers. ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Topping
        fields = ('name',)

class PizzaSerializer(serializers. ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Pizza
        fields = ('name', 'toppings')
```

After that just use [`ListAPIView`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#listapiview) and provide your serializer to it.

```
class PizzaListApiView(ListAPIView):
    queryset = Pizza.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PizzaSerializer
```

**Update**

> How can I create a "nested" queryset?

Nested means with `ForeignKey` or `ManyToManyField` in model, like your `Pizza` model. You could do [`prefetch_related`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) on your queryset, for example if you want to do it explicitly(http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#dealing-with-multiple-objects)

```
queryset = Pizza.objects.all().prefetch_related('toppings')
serializer = PizzaSerializer(queryset, many=True)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response Sardorbek. As mentioned in the last few lines of my question, I would like to achieve this functionality outside of using `ModelSerializer` for custom queryset creations, if possible.

Comment: @aero I don't see problem using `ModelSerializer` and extending it, `ModelSerializer` is subclass of `Serializer`. Which means everything you could do with `Serializer` you could do with `ModelSerializer` and even better it does all work for accessing db for you.

Comment: Your updated fully answered my question. Thanks for your efforts Sardorbek!

Answer (score 0):

For completeness, and others finding this page, below are two different ways to achieve the similar result.

Thanks to Sardorbek for originally answering the question.

The view:

```
class PizzaList(APIView):
    """
    View for the Serializer not using ModelSerializer
    """
    def get(self, request, format=None):
        pizzas = Pizza.objects.all().prefetch_related('toppings')
        serializer = PizzaSerializer(pizzas, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

class PiePizzaList(APIView):
    """
    View for the Serializer useing ModelSerializer
    """
    def get(self, request, format=None):
        pizzas = Pizza.objects.all()
        serializer = PiePizzaSerializer(pizzas, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

The Serializer 1 (without ModelSerializer):

```
class ToppingSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    name = serializers.CharField(required=True, allow_blank=False, max_length=50)

class PizzaSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    name = serializers.CharField(required=True, allow_blank=False, max_length=50)
    toppings = ToppingSerializer(many=True, required=False)
```

OR Serializer 2 (with ModelSerializer):

```
class PieToppingSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Topping
        fields = ('name',)

class PiePizzaSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    name = serializers.CharField(required=True)
    toppings = PieToppingSerializer(many=True, required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Pizza
```